# tkinter enable/disable menu

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I need some help in this.
I want the user to login ...
once he is logged in, only the menu corresponding to the module he is allowed to access will be enabled.
So, I need to disable all the menus (except File and Help) in the beginning..
and I need to enable the corresponding menu after login...

the login code is not written yet.. I just want to see how to do that...
My code is below:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class gv:
    w = 800
    h = 500
    title = 'gsm ...'
    MDLS =   [['File','Settings','_s','Quit'],
            ['main menu','mm1','mm2'],
            ['second menu','sm1','sm2','sm3'],
            ['Help','About']]

class GammaSoft(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, width=gv.w, height=gv.h)
        self.master.title(gv.title)
        self.master.resizable(0,0)
        self.pack_propagate(0)
        self.pack()

        menu_bar = tk.Menu()
        self.nMenu = []
        mc = 0
        for MDL in gv.MDLS:
            self.nMenu.append(tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0))
            for itm in MDL[1:]:
                if itm == '_s':
                    self.nMenu[mc].add_separator()
                else:
                    self.nMenu[mc].add_command(label=itm, command=lambda itm=itm: self.menu_call(itm))
            menu_bar.add_cascade(label=MDL[0], menu=self.nMenu[mc])
            mc += 1
        self.master.config(menu=menu_bar)

        frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame1.pack()
        lblUsername = tk.Label(frame1, text='Username: ')
        lblPassword = tk.Label(frame1, text='Password: ')
        lblModule = tk.Label(frame1, text='Module: ')
        lblSpace1 = tk.Label(frame1, text='      ')
        lblSpace2 = tk.Label(frame1, text='      ')
        self.Username_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.txtUsername = tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=self.Username_var, width=14)
        self.Password_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.txtPassword = tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=self.Password_var, show="x", width=14)
        self.Module_var = tk.StringVar()
        options = [Li[0] for Li in gv.MDLS[1:len(gv.MDLS)-1]]
        self.Module_var.set(options[0])
        self.cmbModule = tk.OptionMenu(frame1, self.Module_var, *tuple(options))
        self.cmbModule.config(takefocus=1, width=14)
        self.btnLiLo = tk.Button(frame1, text='Log in', command=self.LiLo)

        lblUsername.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.txtUsername.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        lblSpace1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        lblPassword.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.txtPassword.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        lblSpace2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        lblModule.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.cmbModule.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.btnLiLo.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

        separator = tk.Frame(self,height=2, bd=1, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        separator.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)

        frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame2_up = tk.Frame(frame2)
        frame2_up.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.TOP)
        frame2_dn = tk.Frame(frame2)
        frame2_dn.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.BOTTOM)

        lblFilter = tk.Label(frame2_up, text='Filter Text: ')
        lblAt = tk.Label(frame2_up, text='At: ')
        lblSpace3 = tk.Label(frame2_up, text='      ')
        self.Filter_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.txtFilter = tk.Entry(frame2_up, textvariable=self.Filter_var, width=14)
        self.At_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.cmbAt = tk.OptionMenu(frame2_up, self.At_var, '')
        self.cmbAt.config(takefocus=1, width=14)
        self.btnGo = tk.Button(frame2_up, text='Apply')
        self.btnClr = tk.Button(frame2_up, text='Clear')
        lblFilter.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.txtFilter.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        lblSpace3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        lblAt.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.cmbAt.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.btnClr.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        self.btnGo.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

        frame2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.log_out

    def log_out(self):
        pass

    def LiLo(self):
        pass

    def print_out(self):
        print('%s, %s!' % (self.greeting_var.get().title(), self.recipient_var.get()))

    def menu_call(self, data):
        print "Once more, clicked / commanded %s" % data

    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()

app = GammaSoft(tk.Tk())
app.run()
```

Comment: I noticed that when I add cascades to menu_bar, If I do it as below, it makes all the menus disabled...

    menu_bar.add_cascade(label=MDL[0], menu=self.nMenu[mc], state=tk.DISABLED)

Comment: I could use below as well... but I want to disable the parent menu, not the items one by one...


    self.nMenu[0].entrycget(0, 'label')
    self.nMenu[0].entryconfigure('Quit', state=tk.DISABLED)
    self.nMenu[0].entryconfigure(0)

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the menu command to see if there is a way to disable something? What research have you done, or what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: @BryanOakley, The only place I reached was, If I disable the menus during creation, I can access the "state".. but if I try to do so later, using `nMenu[0].config(state=tk.DISABLED)` or `tk.NORMAL`... I get an error `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-state"` ... I am trying to read more from the documentations I have.. but No Luck... I appreciate if you made the idea clear for me... I hope you understand what I want to do...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can enable or disable an entire menu by enabling or disabling the item it is connected to.

Here's a contrived example. Use the `Test1` menu to enable or disable the `Test2` menu.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.menubar = tk.Menu()
        self.test1Menu = tk.Menu()
        self.test2Menu = tk.Menu()
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Test1", menu=self.test1Menu)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Test2", menu=self.test2Menu)

        self.test1Menu.add_command(label="Enable Test2", command=self.enable_menu)
        self.test1Menu.add_command(label="Disable Test2", command=self.disable_menu)
        self.test2Menu.add_command(label="One")
        self.test2Menu.add_command(label="Two")
        self.test2Menu.add_command(label="Three")
        self.test2Menu.add_separator()
        self.test2Menu.add_command(label="Four")
        self.test2Menu.add_command(label="Five")

        root.configure(menu=self.menubar)

    def enable_menu(self):
        self.menubar.entryconfig("Test2", state="normal")

    def disable_menu(self):
        self.menubar.entryconfig("Test2", state="disabled")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    app = Example(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I now see how easy and straight-forward the solution is... :) I still have another question.. is it possible to disable/enable a frame ? or should i cycle to its children one by one ?

Answer (score 1):

could use below as well... but I want to disable the parent menu, not the items one by one...

```
self.nMenu[0].entrycget(0, 'label')
self.nMenu[0].entryconfigure('Quit', state=tk.DISABLED) 
self.nMenu[0].entryconfigure(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

To deactivate the whole menu in a menubar write:

```
menubar.entryconfig(1, state = DISABLED)
```