# tkinter enable all the dropdown items from a menu item

Tags: python, tkinter

I have checked on a possible duplicate like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442792/tkinter-enable-disable-menu). However, the recommended action is that I disable the menu item itself. My main aim is to enable all the menu item on each frame switch to make sure that only the ones I need are disabled as the frame switches.

I'm talking about frame switches because my application works by having one main content frame which gets cleaned whenever a new window layout is required. Making it so that I don't have to generate a new window for major changes.

Inadvertently, one drop down item of a menu item may no be required by another layout. So the best option would be to disable it.

Which then brings up the problem. After 2-3 layout switches, I am faced with most if not all drop down items of a menu item being disabled.

If you look at this sample code

```
from tkinter import *


class TopWin:
    def __init__(self, win: Tk):
        win.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)
        self.menu_bar = Menu(root)
        self.menu_1 = Menu(self.menu_bar)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_1, label="Menu 1")
        self.menu_1.add_command(label="Stuff1")
        self.menu_1.add_command(label="Stuff2")
        self.menu_1.add_separator()
        self.menu_1.add_command(label="Settings")
        self.menu_1.add_separator()
        self.menu_1.add_command(label="Stuff")
        self.menu_1.add_command(label="Quit stuff")
        # Disable the ones that shall not be used rn
        self.menu_1.entryconfig('Stuff1', state=DISABLED)
        self.menu_1.entryconfig('Stuff2', state=DISABLED)
        self.menu_1.entryconfig('Settings', state=DISABLED)

        self.menu_2 = Menu(self.menu_bar)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_2, label="Menu 2")
        self.menu_2.add_command(label="Stuff1")
        self.menu_2.add_command(label="Stuff2")
        self.menu_2.add_separator()
        self.menu_2.add_command(label="Other stuff")
        self.menu_2.add_separator()
        self.menu_2.add_command(label="Stuff")

        root['menu'] = self.menu_bar
        self.get_all_menu_item()

    def get_all_menu_item(self):
        _menu_items = self.menu_bar.winfo_children()
        # print(_menu_items) gives 
        # [<tkinter.Menu object .!menu.!menu>, <tkinter.Menu object .!menu.!menu2>]
        for menu_item in _menu_items:
            print(menu_item.winfo_children())
            # printing out the about code is always empty


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    TopWin(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is required due to me using the same menubar for each layout. A possible fix is just making each layout generate their own menubar but that sounds a bit wonky and seems more of a bandaid to the problem than a fix. And also because it sounds like it will require considerably more resources than just enabling them all again and then disabling the ones that's not required.

I'm currently at a lost on how to further approach this. Many thanks for help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating a separate menu for controlling disable|normal settings and then use a list of menu items to determine change.

Something like this.

```py
class TopWin:
    def __init__(self, win: Tk):
        ...
        
        self.menu_3 = Menu(self.menu_bar)
        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(menu = self.menu_3, label = "Control")
        self.menu_3.add_command(label = "Change_1", command = self.able_1)
        self.menu_3.add_separator()
        self.menu_3.add_command(label = "Change_2", command = self.able_2)

        root['menu'] = self.menu_bar
        self.get_all_menu_item()

    def switch(self, m, t):
        for item in t:
            if m.entrycget(item, "state") == DISABLED:
                m.entryconfig(item, state = NORMAL)
            else:
                m.entryconfig(item, state = DISABLED)

    def able_1(self):
        self.switch(self.menu_1, ['Stuff1', 'Stuff2', 'Settings'])

    def able_2(self):
        self.switch(self.menu_2, ["Stuff3", "Stuff4", "Other stuff"])
```

Comment: A good suggestion but I don't think this is good for my use case. I could see how I can improve my current implementation from this.... but the problem lies in the snippet I provided. I will edit the code snippet I provided when I get home. Since your implementation is probably far better than my current approach.